# mysql Search an email and domain name with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, search, join, multiple-tables

I got 3 mysql tables:

`unsubscribers` => `(id, email)`

`bounces` => `(id, email, bounce_reason)`

`blacklists` => `(id, domain)`

Suppose for instance we have to search Email ID: `something@someone.com` and Domain: `someone.com` (i.e of the email ID)

I want to write such a query that will search `Email ID` existing in  `unsubscribers` or `bounces`, or the `domain` which exists in `blacklists`

So it will be like, if either of Email ID or Domain exists in these tables, I should get the result as 1 or 0. If this is not possible, atleast I should get the data

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to it. The query below does it all

```
SELECT (SELECT count(`email`) FROM `unsubscribers` WHERE `email` = 'rsakhale@gmail.com') AS `unsubscribers`,
(SELECT count(`email`) FROM `bounces` WHERE `email` = 'rsakhale@gmail.com') AS `bounces`,
(SELECT count(`name`) FROM `blacklists` WHERE `name` = 'gmail.com') AS `blacklists`
```

And it returns

```
+---------------+---------+------------+
| unsubscribers | bounces | blacklists |
+---------------+---------+------------+
|             1 |       0 |          0 |
+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Ahh, it was a noob question :'(

Comment: I believe still this will be execution of 3 queries as all tables execution would be done. Not sure if JOINs would have helped here as there are no references available

Comment: Can anyone help convert this subquery to joins ??